# Changing a Toggle buttons Background

Tags: java, android, eclipse, background, togglebutton

I want to change the toggle button background to an image where I click and it gets darker and then once I release it reverts back to the same image. I've managed to successfully do this with a button but I require a toggle button for my app. I tried this with the toggle button and only managed to change the  background image of the toggle button. however, the little green check box thing was still there.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the xml drawable for the toggle button is better for your requirement . click [here](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/) for styling your toggle buttons